# product added to wishlist from compare window added twice

Tags: magento-1.7

I added a product to compare and from the compare window I added the product to wishlist, then same product got added twice.

I had this issue in the magento installation for my client. Then I tried it on the default installation and had the same issue. Is this magento bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the issue was due to this code segment in the file catalog/product/compare/list.phtml:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <ul class="add-to-links">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item);?>" class="link-wishlist" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)" is causing the product to be added to wishlist in the parent browser window while its being added to the current window as well resulting the product to be added twice in the wishlist.

I fixed this issue by changing the onclick value to

```
onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist'); ?>', true)"
```

This solved the issue.